# Connecting to a raspberry pi 4 using a docking station?

Tags: boot, pi-4, power, display, usb-c

I've just purchased the Pi 4 model B and am buying the parts I need. I have a docking station I usually use for my laptop and was wondering if the Pi can be fully set up using a docking station via the USB-C port? I.e. this connection would provide everything including the power, display monitor, keyboard and mouse.

I know the question is generic; I just want a general idea of whether this is possible? If so, are certain brands more compatible/better suited than others?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Too open for opinions TBH - it may be possible but so much will depends on the hardware inside the docking station (and that changes even within the same 'part number' just ask DELL / HP < grrr > ) getting a solid answer is about as handy as Googling for reviews of docking stations.  NexDoc had a Pi one (eBay 4 years old USB 2) moved to phones as bigger market - look at the Pi 400 for an 'all-in-on' solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB-C connector on RaspberyPi4 is used mainly to deliver power.

It can not be used as a normal USB-C port.

However it can be used as an USB2 OTG port.

Comment: @Miliways thanks for the heads up. I changed word "only" to "mainly" and added your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The Pi4 MAY use a USB-C connector BUT it is NOT a  USB-C port so NO

Answer (score 1):

I have a RPi4B connected to a recent Targus model ~177 -- downloaded the displaylink installer from targus 5.3.1.34 and it seems to run flawlessly -- w/Acer 232 touch display even touch works (certainly handy when my somewhat flaky Logitech K400 stops tracking!) W/all the USB3 ports on the Targus plus the Acer display hub it's a real dream machine -- ONE downside I recently observed -- if the Targus is NOT connected, I get no video on either of the Acer inputs from either of the Pi4 ports using either of the two adapter cables that once worked!  Now I need to figure out how to get the original display config to work (there is some display reset and input scanning happening at boot time, but never anything more than some varying shades of black screen --looks like I need to refresh my memory from days long past when I needed to get down and dirty with xconfig  drivers for old ATI desktop cards on Fedora!!!

Answer (score 0):

The USB-C connection on a RPI4 is *only" for power, it's theoretically possible to use one of the usb-3 sockets (the blue ones) but you might have some serious configuration ahead of you